# Merging two dataframes on the same type column gives me wrong result

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframes, assume A and B, which have been created after reading the sheets of an Excel file and performing some basic functions. I need to `merge right` the two dataframes on a column named ID which has first been converted to `astype(str)` for both dataframes.

The ID column of the left Dataframe (A) is:

```
0        5815518813016
1        5835503994014
2        5835504934023
3        5845535359006
4        5865520960012
5        5865532845006
6        5875531550008
7        5885498289039
8     5885498289039_A2
9     5885498289039_A3
10    5885498289039_X2
11    5885498289039_X3
12       5885509768698
13       5885522349999
14       5895507791025
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

The ID column of the right Dataframe (B) is:

```
0        5835503994014
1        5845535359006
2        5835504934023
3        5815518813016
4     5885498289039_A1
5     5885498289039_A2
6     5885498289039_A3
7     5885498289039_X1
8     5885498289039_X2
9     5885498289039_X3
10       5885498289039
11       5865532845006
12       5875531550008
13       5865520960012
14       5885522349998
15       5895507791025
16       5885509768698
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

However, when I merge the two, the rest of the columns of the left (A) dataframe become "empty" (np.nan) except for the rows where the ID does not contain only numbers but letters too. This is the `pd.merge()` I do:

```
A_B=A.merge(B[['ID','col_B']], left_on='ID', right_on='ID', how='right')
```

Do you have any ideas what might be so wrong? Your input is valuable.

Comment: You might be mistaking the names of the columns, or anything else. It is not possible to reproduce your question, as you didn't give an example actually showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning all values in both columns into strings:
`A['ID'] = A['ID'].astype(str)`
`B['ID'] = B['ID'].astype(str)`

Generally, when a merge like this doesn't work, I would try to debug by printing out the unique values in each column to check if anything pops out (usually dtype issues).

Comment: I had so many dataframes and applied so many times ```filter()``` and ```drop_duplicates()``` in this project that I had missed the parent dataframe of df_B. I realised it when I started checking the type of the values of the columns ID of each dataframe, when suddenly for one df the type was ```int``` instead of ```str```. Thank you so much!